# Business Object XI 3.0 error

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

In Business Object XI 3.0, while logging in publishing wizard I am getting following error.  Any Help please

---

### Logon Error

### Transport error: Communication failure.(FWM 00001)

### OK

Even CMC option is also not working.  Yesterday also it was giving same problem.  I had reinstalled the software. then it started working.  Now today it is again giving same error.  This happen second time.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

make sure your hosts file is right,eg 10.1.1.1 serverdomain.ping the server make sure the network is working.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your firewall is blocking it, also double check your credentials within the cmc are correct and that there is connectivity between your database and your server. Also try connecting through the Administrative account.